# Accessing each member in a class in Java like in struct in C

Tags: java

Im a beginner in Java. I read that `structs` in C are similar to classes in Java, but I have the following doubt.

I have a class as follows:

```
public class operations {
    public Integer[] stream;
    public Integer[] functi;
    public String[] name;
    public Integer[] funcgroup;
}
```

I get an input from the user for `name` and compare it with the name array in the class and if there is a match, I want to return the records for all the other fields corresponding to the name.

For eg. if name corresponds to `String[5]`, then I want to output all the records corresponding to [5]..i.e `stream[5]`, `functi[5]`, `functigroup[5]`.

How can I do this?

**EDIT Now my program looks like this:**

```
public class operations extends DefFunctionHandler {
public ArrayList<Integer> stre = null;
public ArrayList<Integer> functii = null;
public ArrayList<String> nmee = null;
public ArrayList<Integer> funcigroup = null;
public ArrayList<Integer> sourcee = null;

public void filter(String x){
    DefFunctionHandler defi = new DefFunctionHandler();
    functii = defi.getFunc();
    stre = defi.getStream();
    nmee = defi.getName();
    funcigroup = defi.getFuncgroup();
    sourcee = defi.getSource();

    Map<String, operations> map = new HashMap<String, operations>();
    operations operations = new operations(0, 0, x, 0, 0);
    map.put(x, operations); 
    operations op = map.get("flush");
    System.out.println(op.toString());

}
```

And I get a message saying that I have to declare a constructor for operations with parameters(int, int, string,int, int). Can anyone tell me if my Map interface implementation is correct?

Comment: It is better you can create a class with all the attributes and have a List of that class.

Comment: Structs are a lower level concept which can be used to "manually" implement objects such as classes, but the two concepts do not directly correspond.  If you want to enumerate the member elements of a struct-live view of a class you may look into reflection, however if this is an operation you are anticipating already it may be better to explicitly code method(s) for obtaining the data.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot Ok how do I access the members in the List then?..sorry if this is a stupid question..but wud be nice if you can tell me

Comment: I suggest you implement this structure as a collection of objects.  If you use the name as a key, you can use a Map.

Comment: Please see [this very similar question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/199644/2234) from [programmers.SE].

Comment: @JoachimSauer Can you take a look at my program and tell me what if my implementation is correct or where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user2358330: I have absolutely no idea: what is `DefFunctionHandler`?  Why do you both *extend* and *use* it? Why do you still have `ArrayList<Integer>`? Should a single `operations` object have *multiple* "stree" values? What is up with `stre`, `functii`, `nmee`? Why not use `stream`, `func` and `name`, like `DefFunctionHandler` does (it seems to be talking about the same things). You are *using* a constructor, but have not declared it.

Comment: @JoachimSauer To answer your questions: `DefFunctionHandler` is a class where i get the input from another external file. The `DefFunctionHandler` class is being called multiple times to read from the external file using a interface. So I store the values from external file inside `DefFunctionHandler` in an arraylist and that is why I use those arraylist values here inside `operations` class. Im quite new to Java, so Im not sure whether what Im doing is correct. And how shud I call the map Interface and use it (without calling a constructor)? Or is constructor necessary?

Comment: @user2358330: I'm sorry, but doing a full review of your code is simply not feasible in the comments. 1.) it's very strange to *extend* **and** *use* a single class in the same class. 2.) you're still using parallel lists of string/int/... where you *probably* should be using a *single* list (or map) of Operations objects (with one string/int/... each. Now you've got a map of operations with multiple lists each, which *seems* to be too many levels of repetition. (but we don't know, because we have no clear description of the problem domain).

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thanks for the reply! I understand what you say. I just have one last question. If I use a single list of operations, how do I add the Arraylist of values, that I have in there?

Answer (score 5):

You should store your operation objects into a Map

A map works with key/value, you put an id into the map, and you can retrieve the corresponding key.

In your example, use the class Operation :

```
public class Operation { 
    public int stream;
    public int functi;
    public name; 
    public int funcgroup;
}
```

and a map like this :

```
Map<String, Operation> map = new HashMap<String, Operation>();
Operation operation = new Operation(0,0,"name5", 0);
map.put("name5", operation);
```

You can retrieve your Operation object with :

```
Operation op = map.get("name5");
```

Comment: I have the program using Map as you suggested, but it says that I should create a constructor for operations to accept (int,int,string,int,int). Can anyone tell me what is wrong in my program? is my usage of Map interface correct?

Comment: You should have a constructor for the Operation class.

    public Operation(int stream, int functi, String name, int funcgroup) {
        this.stream = stream;
        this.functi = functi;
        this.name = name;
        this.funcgroup = funcgroup;
    }